# How to check uniq constraint on update/ insert in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple gridview and sqldatasource to bind data to gridview  , SqlDatabase 
I'm trying to set to a column a constraint for unique so If I add new row or update a row and the value already exists It won't update.

For the column Name , I set ->Indexes/keys -> new -> choosed column Name -> Unique key .

How can I get the error when it says already exists , in a label?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First create a procedure as this:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
( 
@myUniquecolumn as varchar(20),
@ID    as int
)
AS
DECLARE @ReturnValue int
IF EXISTS (SELECT myUniquecolumn FROM mytable WHERE myUniquecolumn=@myUniquecolumn)
BEGIN
-- if the value already exist return 1
SELECT @ReturnValue = 1;
RETURN @ReturnValue;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
update mytable set myUniquecolumn=@myUniquecolumn where ID=@ID
SELECT @ReturnValue = 0;
RETURN @ReturnValue;
END
```

then use this procedure in ur sqldatasource for update. Follow this [turtorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record) to how to add output parameter to sql data source.

after your aspx sqldatasource should be like similar to this:

```
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="myUniquecolumn" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Int32" Direction="ReturnValue" Name="uniqtest" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

then wirte following code in your code behind file.

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Updated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    int uniquecolumn= (int)e.Command.Parameters["@uniqtest"].Value;

  if (uniquecolumn == 0)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "fail";
    }
  }
```

hope it helps.... :)